# Joining a list of strings efficiently over multiple lines with a maximum linesize

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, concatenation

I'm looking for a way to make lines out of a big list of strings.
String length could be from 4 characters up to 20.
The line size maximum is 255 characters.
The strings should be be separated by comma+space (which of course should be counted as 2 lost characters)

I want to fill the lines as efficient as possible and try to use all the 255 characters for as long as possible.
The order of the strings doesn't matter.
Then, I want to return a list of all those joined lines.

I know the basic:

```
', '.join(my_list_of_strings)
```

and then split at best below 255 characters, but that's not the efficiency I need.

If there's a good CSV solution I accept that as well (just comma separated strings with a max line size of 255)

EDIT:
Textwrap does the thing, but not as intelligent as I want:
With my question text as string and 20char width:

```
print textwrap.fill(my_text, width=20)

I'm looking for a
way to make lines
out of a big list of
strings. String
length could be from
4 characters up to
20. The line size
maximum is 255
characters.
```

What I want is this:

```
I'm looking for a to
way make lines a big
out of list of could
strings. String from
length be characters
4 up to 20. The line
size maximum is 255
characters.
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure of what you're asking, but check out the [textwrap](https://docs.python.org/2/library/textwrap.html) module.

Comment: So you want to reorder the strings in such a way that it minimizes the number of lines without any line exceeding 255 characters?

Comment: On second read, this sounds like a [bin packing problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem), which is NP hard. If you find an algorithm that works fast on all inputs, make sure to pick up your [Millennium Prize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millennium_Prize_Problems#P_versus_NP).

Comment: @schwobaseggl, basically yes.
I want to convert that big list of strings and join those strings in X-number of lines, where I want to try to keep X as low as possible.

Comment: @Kevin, I'll look into that module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Greedy approach without much sophistication:

**1.** sort the strings by length, longest first

**2.** add strings from the front until you would exceed 255

**3.** hand-pick ((binary-)search) a string by length to get you as close to 
255 as possible

**4.** still not exactly at 255: remove last string added and repeat ***3.**

**5.** (optional) if there is no string to get you to exactly 255, search for a combo of 2 (3, ...) strings that gets you there.

**6.** repeat **1-5** until no more strings

Comment: Thanks, seems like a good approach, since Kevin already pointed out about the 'bin packing problem' and thus the complexity of what I'm looking for.